# In linear regression, does the parameter confidence interval is based in the mean confidence interval?

Tags: regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model

If I have a sample and calculate the interval for the A and B parameter of the linear regression for that sample, for a given x that is the independent variable of my real data, and Y that is the predicted value of the linear regression for this x value, does  Y +- (Upper/Bottom limit of the A parameter)*X + (Upper/Bottom limit of the B parameter) is the same as the confidence interval for the mean of y (dependent variable of the real data) for a given x?

Comment: Try it out in your favorite software package!

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the [tag:self-study]
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).